# The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate

i just cant understand this error.
what is client's truststore?
[i inserted certificate correctly]
 but i am not sure if it's valid because when i installed it on my pc i sow something like this certification is expired.

the stack trace is:

aused by: java.io.IOException: IOException invoking https://192.168.238.46:8400/yaghut/soap/soap_tosan: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1337)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1321)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:623)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The https URL hostname does not match the Common Name (CN) on the server certificate in the client's truststore.  Make sure server certificate is correct, or to disable this check (NOT recommended for production) set the CXF client TLS configuration property "disableCNCheck" to true.
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1235)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:182)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1294)
    ... 13 more

Answer (score 0):

well, i used this code but it should be used only for test.
and the host certification was expired also.

```
 SoapServices service = soapTosan.getSoapPort();
    HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(service).getConduit();
    TLSClientParameters tlsCP = new TLSClientParameters();
    tlsCP.setDisableCNCheck(true);
    httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsCP);
```